# how to bind non array elements of a non array to an array?

Tags: angular8

I want a nonarray element to be put into an array
  Leadjournal; is a property that is of type any. I want it to be converted to an array so that the elements in it will not be affected when changed to an array. For eg: creationDate is a variable of property Leadjournal, but upon changing it to an array it shows that it cant be converted to an array.